# Убрать div после клика вне его

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть `div` который отрисовывается следующим кодом:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#link-member', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var that = jQuery(this);
  var url = that.attr('href');

  that.before('<div id="members"></div>');
  jQuery.post(url, function(data) {},'html')
    .done(function(data) {
      jQuery('#members').append(data);
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
      alert(data.responseText);
    });
});
```

Вопрос в том, как закрыть и очистить `div`. Если клик был произведен вне отрисованого `div`.

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, под *закрыть и очистить div* Вы имеете ввиду *скрыть и очистить отрисованный div* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если под *закрыть и очистить div* Вы имеете ввиду *скрыть и очистить отрисованный div*, то так:

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    var container = $("#members");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        //проверяем, чтобы клик был не на блоке и не на потомках блока
        container.hide().html('');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="members">test test test</div>
```

Comment: Отлично подходит, спасибо )